# Python Combinations with conditions

Tags: python, combinations

I have a piece of code and I am using itertools to generate the combinations.

```
import itertools

charset = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.upper())

for it in itertools.combinations(charset, 16):
    while (it[0] < 'F' and
           it[1] < 'H' and it[1] > 'A' and
           it[2] < 'K' and it[2] > 'B' and
           it[3] < 'L' and it[3] > 'C' and
           it[4] < 'N' and it[4] > 'D' and
           it[5] < 'T' and it[5] > 'G' and
           it[6] < 'V' and it[6] > 'H' and
           it[7] < 'Y' and it[7] > 'I' and
           it[8] < 'Z' and it[8] > 'J' and
           ord(it[9]) < 91):
        print (it)
        break
```

This gets the job, done but I am trying to look for a better way that can perhaps avoid the checking of the while conditions and directly generate the combinations in order to save time. Is there another itertools function, or something of that sort?

Comment: Are the conditions hard-coded? How did you determine the letters to use in the conditions? If they're constants, you could pretty easily throw them in a dictionary and use a for loop to do the validation

Comment: Why `while cond: break` rather than `if cond:`?

Comment: For the record, what @Jab meant was `'A' < it[1] < 'H'`, which is valid Python.

Answer (score 1):

This creates your first 9 items.  If the last 7 are chosen from the whole set, I suppose you could append the result of `itertools.combinations(...,7)`, but since this set will already generate about a billion entries, it's not clear what you'll do with this.

```
import itertools

items = [ 
  'ABCDE',
  'BCDEFG',
  'CDEFGHIJ',
  'DEFGHIJK',
  'EFGHIJKLM',
  'HIJKLMNOPQRS',
  'IJKLMNOPQRSTU',
  'JKLMNOPQRSTUVWX',
  'KLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
]

for it in itertools.product(*items):
    print (it)
```

Comment: Hey, this solution is great although its printing out the product instead of the combinations :/. The amount of tuples generated (that pass the conditions) by the code in question are about 4516772.

Comment: That's simply not true.  In your first 9 entries, you have 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15, and 15 items.  Multiplied together, that's 606,528,000.  26**7 is 8,031,810,176.  Multiplied together, that's a very, very large number.